# Why is `outer` slower than a `for` loop in R?

Tags: r, performance, vectorization

```r
u <- rnorm(10000)
v <- rnorm(10000)

# `outer`
system.time(mat1 <- outer(u, v , `<`))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    1.80    1.34    3.32 

# `for` loop
system.time({
  mat2 <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(u), ncol = length(v))
  for(i in seq_along(v)) {
    mat2[, i] <- u < v[i]
  }
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.97    0.02    1.01 

identical(mat1, mat2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I tried it and it was slower, repeat this many times.

Comment: I repeated this many times and `outer` is always slower

Comment: Incidentally, why are you using outer here? Why not do u<v?

Comment: `u<v` would't work since one side has to be of length one.

Comment: I get (almost) exactly the same `system.time` for both (`0.45/0.17/0.62` Vs `0.45/0.18/0.63`)

Comment: I also tried this a few times (with a few different sizes of matrix) and `outer` was always slightly faster. What speed difference do you get if you run ```mat3 <- `<`(rep(u, times = ceiling(length(v)/length(u))), rep(v, rep.int(length(u), length(v))))``` ? That's essentially what `outer is doing.

Comment: Probably because of memory allocation. `outer` does the whole operation at once, hence needs to allocate a lot of memory, while the `for` loop does many simple operations. If you'll test it on `u <- rnorm(100) ; v <- rnorm(100)`, you'll see `outer` is faster. Usually, this is the tradeoff between loop and vectorized functions- if the operation is simple but needs a lot of memory- loop is better, but if the operation is complicated, then doing it per iteration is costly, while a compiled code will much preferable

Comment: Also, why would you expect `outer` to be faster than `for` loops?

Comment: Best of both worlds: `vapply(seq_along(v), \(i) u < v[i], logical(length(u)))`

Comment: @SamR Indeed `mat3 <- `<`(rep(u, times = ceiling(length(v)/length(u))), rep(v, rep.int(length(u), length(v)))))` is way faster than `outer` and for loop

Comment: @sindri_baldur yes, the larger the matrix becomes the better `vapply()` performs, for very small matrices `outer()` actually performs better

Answer (score 8):

#### Allocating and destroying memory takes time

If you use `bench::press()` with the four options set out you can get the sense that the method with the most memory allocations takes longest, as suggested by David Arenburg in the comments.

The four options are:

1. `outer()`.
2. A `for` loop.
3. `vapply()` (from comment by sindri_baldur).
4. `` `<`(rep(x), rep(y)) `` (exactly what `outer()` is doing under the hood).

I like [`bench`](https://bench.r-lib.org/) because it shows memory usage. Each facet in this plot shows the speed of these four approaches with an `n*n` matrix, and levels of garbage collection.

[image]

With 100 rows, `vapply` is slower than the other  methods, and there's no difference in `gc` (garbage collection).

However, once the data is larger than that, we can see that `vapply()` does a lot less garbage collection and is a lot faster.

Similarly, in the final facet (`1e4` rows and columns), we can see that the `for` loop has less garbage collection and tends to be faster than `outer()`.

#### `vapply()` uses the least RAM

You might suspect that `vapply()` has less garbage collection because it leaves more garbage uncollected. However, if we look at the total RAM usage, we can see that actually it uses about a third of the RAM of `outer()`:

[image]

Note: I don't know how it could actually use 0 bytes in creating a 1x1 matrix - but if you're really comparing two scalars you would probably not use a matrix at all.

#### What do the garbage collection levels mean?

See the R Internals chapter, [The write barrier and the garbage collector](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#The-write-barrier):

> There are three levels of collections. Level 0 collects only the youngest generation, level 1 collects the two youngest generations and level 2 collects all generations. After 20 level-0 collections the next collection is at level 1, and after 5 level-1 collections at level 2. Further, if a level-n collection fails to provide 20% free space (for each of nodes and the vector heap), the next collection will be at level n+1. (The R-level function gc() performs a level-2 collection.)

The way to understand this is that if a function is creating more temporary objects, and then destroying them, it will do more allocations and have more garbage collection.

#### Code to run the simulation and generate the first plot

```r
sizes <- c(1, 1e2, 1e3, 1e4)

results <- bench::press(
    size = sizes,
    {
        set.seed(1)
        u <- rnorm(size)
        v <- rnorm(size)

        bench::mark(
            min_iterations = 10,
            check = FALSE,
            outer = {
                mat <- outer(u, v, `<`)
            },
            loop = {
                mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(u), ncol = length(v))
                for (i in seq_along(v)) {
                    mat[, i] <- u < v[i]
                }
                mat
            },
            vapply = {
                mat <- vapply(seq_along(v), \(i) u < v[i], logical(length(u)))
            },
            seq = {
                mat <- as.matrix(
                    `<`(
                        rep(u, times = ceiling(length(v) / length(u))),
                        rep(v, rep.int(length(u), length(v)))
                    ),
                    nrow = length(u)
                )
            }
        )
    }
)

ggplot2::autoplot(results) +
    ggplot2::facet_wrap(ggplot2::vars(size),scales="free_x")
```

#### Code for the second plot

```r
library(ggplot2)
p  <- results  |>
    dplyr::mutate(
        expr = attr(expression, "description"),
        size = as.factor(size))  |>
    ggplot() +
        geom_col(aes(
            x = reorder(expr, mem_alloc),
            y = mem_alloc,
            fill = size
        ), color= "black") +
        facet_wrap(vars(size), scales="free_y") +
    labs(
        title = "Total RAM usage", 
        y = "Bytes", 
        x = "Expression"
    )
```

Disclaimer: These are the results on one machine (an unremarkable fairly old laptop). I didn't get the same magnitude of discrepancy between `outer()` and the `for` loop as you did so your results may differ.